# Error de referencia no capturado: $ no está definido

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

me encuentro con un problema. Tengo un login que al momento de ingresar las credenciales me manda el siguiente error **Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at** Estoy haciéndolo con PHP y JS, les dejo el código de mi código PHP y de mi código JS donde manda hacer las peticiones de mi PHP

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./login/style.css">
    <title>Sistema de Reportes - Login</title>

</head>

<body>
    <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
    <form class="login100-form validate-form" action="" method="POST" id="login-form">
    <div class="main-wrap">
        <h1 class="titulo">
            <span class="typed"></span>
        </h1>
       <form class="login" action="" method="POST" id="login-form">
        <div class="login-main" method="POST" id="login-form">
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Usuario" class="box1 border">
         <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" class="box1 border2">
         <button type="submit" name="submit"class="send">Go</button>
           </div>
        </form>
            
    </div>
    </form>
    <!-- partial -->
    <script src="vista/vendor/typed/typed.js"></script>
    <script src="login/main.js"></script>
    <script src="login/login.js"></script>
    <script src="vista/vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

les comparto mi código JS donde hago la validación

```js
$('#login-form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var username = $.trim($('#username').val());
    var password = $.trim($('#password').val());

    if (username.length == "" || password == "") {
        Swal.fire({
            type: 'warning',
            title: 'Debe ingresar un usuario y/o password',
        });
        return false;
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            url: "controlador/login.php",
            type: "POST",
            datatype: "json",
            data: { username: username, password: password },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data == "null") {
                    Swal.fire({
                        type: 'error',
                        title: 'Usuario y/o password incorrecta',
                    });
                } else {

                    Swal.fire({
                        //position: 'top-end',
                        icon: 'success',
                        title: '¡Conexión existosa!',
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        timer: 2000
                      })
                   .then((result) => {
                        if (result.value) {
                            window.location.href = "dashboard/reportes.php";
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
        });
    }
    
});
```

Cuando depuro mi código en el navegador me muestra el siguiente error. No sé qué estoy haciendo de manera incorrecta, ya ingrese los id en mi código PHP para identificar mi formulario.

[image: error]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined

Comment: @cris223511-dev No todos saben ingles y a veces la traducción puede perder un poco de sentido. En cuanto a tu error. Jquery debe ser definido e instancia antes de tus otros scripts, es decir cambia el orden en el que se llaman en el `html`